# removing the white border around an image python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to remove the white color border in the following image:

[image: this is the image that I want to remove the border]

I have set an upper and lower boundary and iterate through row by row and column by column to remove the white border but the result is not successful. There are still white areas in the image:

[image: processed image]

I have tried contours bounding box method as well but it doesn't work for some number plates and doesn't identify the border correctly.

Can you recommend me a way to remove the white color area in the original image?

Comment: In your first screenshot there isn't any "a" in "border", otherwise it means something completely different.

Comment: You seem to have provided a picture of your picture with a surrounding window frame and title-bar rather than the image itself - that is not very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Is your white border never path-connected to your white symbols?
If this is true, I would suggest a [region growing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing) algorithm, like the "fill color pot" in MS Paint.
You start with a "seed point" in (0,0), and look for the neighboring pixels. If they are white too, you paint them in black and they become seed, ... you iterate until you have no more white neighbor.

If you prefer to write less code, you could negate the image (black becomes white and white becomes black), then use findContours(), select the contour with a pixel in (0,0) and fill it in black, then reverse again the colors. The drawback is that it performs more operations than needed and I am not 100% sure about this latter solution.